# Is there a place to store VBA code that's accessible to all Microsoft Office products..?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-word

Is there a way of storing VBA source code that's common and accessible to all Microsoft Office products..? I have a variety of functions which I use in both Access and Excel, and sometimes even Word. I modify and add to the the functions and modules frequently. The copying, pasting, and maintaining of code between projects can get tedious, and I inevitably overlook something.

I know I could do something like write a class/ocx/addin in VB6 or DotNet, compile it, and reference it in my VBA projects, but I was hoping for something more simple.

If there was a way to store VBA code in independent files, and open them with the VBA IDE in a standalone mode of some sort, that would be outstanding, but I know the IDE doesn't work that way...as far as I know.

Comment: You can create an add-in. The other easy way is to create a module file which you can import in the VBA IDE

Comment: Yes, I considered those, but I was hoping for something simple as I suggested - some sort of common location. I'll have various that are forming in my mind of an addin that can be loaded in all Office products and would keep the source code synchronized...somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I could do something like write a class/ocx/addin in VB6 or DotNet, compile it, and reference it in my VBA projects, but I was hoping for something more simple.

Unfortunately that's your best bet.

As you know VBA code is hosted, wrapped-up in a host document: a VBA add-in is still tied to its host document (.xlam, etc.), and as such can't be shared with another host.

In VBA-land what's *meant* to be shared between VBA projects, is *type libraries* - things you compile separately from the VBA project, and *reference* from as many projects as you like.

If you have a VB6 IDE, you can compile a 32-bit DLL that VBA projects can reference. The problem is that it won't work with 64-bit hosts - the solution is a .NET type library, written in the .NET language of your choice, made COM-visible. Note that COM-compatibility does restrict what you can expose in your API: for example you can't expose generics, and method overloads will look weird.

If a type library isn't an avenue you wish to explore, then your choices are rather limited, and IMO sub-optimal.

IMO the only thing that *can* "work" is a bunch of exported code files in some common folder, and the VBA projects that need to use that code need to literally import these code files. The risk here being, that if you make any changes, other VBA projects using an unmodified version of that code will not "see" these changes, IOW by doing that you're multiplying the number of times you need to fix a bug by the number of projects using that code.

Or you could have some code that uses the VBIDE extensibility type library to ensure the set of imported modules always match exactly with the exported files in that common location.

Comment: Yes, I understand the encapsulation issue, that's why I was thinking an addin would be the way to go. But...not an addin for the Office product, but an addin for the VBA IDE window. I have one I downloaded called PrettyCodePrint. Installed it in the Excel VBA IDE, and lo & behold it magically appeared in the Access VBA IDE too. I'd discovered that IDE addins *are* common across all Office products, so I think that's the way to go. I'd have to devise some sort of sync scheme, perhaps sense when windows are activated/deactivated, and then copy to/from as necessary.

Comment: I do have VB6; it's installed in an Oracle Virtual Box VM. That's why I mentioned creating an addin with VB6; I've already dabbled in it. I have the O'Reilly book "Developing Visual Basic Addins", and I'm quite familiar with the VBIDE OL and have done some odd development projects with it. For the purpose of the discussion, I would just have to settle on a sync trigger and then how the sync would take place. Piece of cake..! Especially in between my other projects. heh =-)

Comment: If you only need to target 32-bit hosts that can indeed be an option - then again, IMO it would be much simpler to maintain the VB6 type library as a VB6 DLL, and reference that type library in any VBA project that needs it - your call!

Comment: Sorry, my C# is a bit shaky. I do know some in a tertiary sort of way; I recently went back to school to finish my diploma in programming, and I had four semesters of JAVA. I accidentally discovered a side-effect: I realized I could read C* code. But...not write it. Yet.

Comment: I've had the same issue before, copying code. @Mat'sMug suggestion to build a library is probably your best bet. Previous co-worker introduced me to C# and finding Rubberduck a month later was a no-brainer on how to learn. Please drop by the pond (AKA war room). ***Diclaimer:*** I contribute to RD and have learned a lot from the group.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use VBA in the same Office program (e.g. one Excel file to another, or one Access file to another), you don't need to use any special kind of file. You can add a reference to an external database or worksheet with macro's enabled.

Navigate Tools - References - Browse - Excel/Access file - Add the file

See the following screenshot:

[image]

You can't use files across different Office applications this way, but you shouldn't. Each application has different built-in functions, so your code is likely incompatible anyway.

Comment: Each host application adds its type library as a reference to the VBA project, yes. I suppose it depends on what you consider "built-in"... There is *a lot* of custom code that can very well not use any host-specific library (e.g. a progress indicator class and userform, a custom collection class, string utility functions, etc.), so the final assumption in this answer is quite likely off. Also OP is specifically asking about sharing code *between different hosts*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I was wondering if I should add it. It's indeed not fully true (as an Access programmer, I tend to use `Nz` a lot which is unavailable in other Office programs, so a lot of my modules will fail to compile). But anyway, it's a limit, you might want to circumvent it, but as far as I know, you can't.

Comment: Doesn't the Excel/Access file you're referencing in your new/existing project just need to reference the relevant Microsoft (Host) XX.0 Object Library? Worst case scenario your new/existing project also needs to reference the relevant Microsoft (Host) XX.0 Object Library.

Comment: @Tigregalis You just can't add references to files for a different Office program. You could indeed try to make the code work by importing the relevant libraries, but as you can't reference an Access file from Excel, or an Excel file from Access, it's no use

Comment: I mean with respect to for instance making use of `Access.Nz`, which isn't available across all applications, in your "addin". Let's say a function `Test` within "addin" uses `Access.Nz`; you need to make use of `Test` in your "new project" so you add a reference to "addin", and "addin" already has a reference to "Microsoft Access Object Library" - will `Access.Nz` be available to "new project" or will "new project" need to add a reference to "Microsoft Access Object Library"?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.

Comment: Omg I had no idea that other document files could be referenced..! That's very interesting, it's got the gears turning in my head. I just checked in Excel and Word and it works in them too. But...in a way I've already been doing a variation of this anyways. I save all my Excel macros in the personal xls file, and my Word macros in the normal dot.

I cross-reference products regularly, For instance, I've referenced the Excel OL in my Access projects so I can create sheets, export data to them, and format them with way more control than the native Access exporter.

Comment: And because I reference many OLs in my Access projects, and because I've gotten burned over the years, I tend to write all my code with the procedure names prefaced with the library name. For instance VBA.Mid(1,"blah",1) instead of simply Mid(1,"blah",1).