# How to set a VBA global variable in one project & use in another project?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

**Background**

A version control database called VCS (project name = VCS) is used for a variety of version control tasks.

Various other application databases have VCS set up as a reference.

In these app databases a global variable is set to identify which tables within them to backup:

`Global Const APP_TABLES_TO_BACKUP = "tbl1, tbl2, tbl5"`

**Problem**

The question is, how to reference this `APP_TABLES_TO_BACKUP`constant from the VCS project?

Because each app has its own setting for this value, it makes sense to set the value in a module of the app and call that value from the VCS database project.

Any ideas on how to do that?

**So far...**

I've searched and found Chip Pearson's [Understanding Scope](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx), but not quite gotten how to set and reference the global variable.

In the immediate window of the app I can type `?APP_TABLES_TO_BACKUP` and retrieve the tables, but I can't seem to see how to reference that same variable from the VCS database so it can be used in a subroutine there.

*Any ideas?*

Comment: `Global` keyword has been deprecated over 20 years ago. `Public` does exactly the same thing. If you have projects A and B, and you need project A to use code in project B, then you need project A to have a *reference* to project B. But really, consider reading/writing the configuration settings in some file instead.

Comment: If this is Access, wouldn't it make more sense to have a **table** called `APP_TABLES_TO_BACKUP` in each individual database to specify that information?

Comment: @YowE3K gosh I always miss the Access tag lol

Comment: @Mat's Mug - Yeah, it should read `Public` vs. `Global`... and I probably should use the `TempVars` collection.... or a table like @YowE3K metntions (though I'd rather not add that to the app since it's only used when I'm doing versioning). Hmmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my earlier post apparently didn't come through a couple days ago...

After searching a bit further I came across [Paul Murray's custom database properties](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-09.html) which work nicely.

With some tweaks I created a module that includes generic property add, remove methods.

```
' ---------------------------------
' FUNCTION:     AddDbProperty
' Description:  add custom properties to a database application
' ---------------------------------
Public Function AddDbProperty(DbProperty As String, _
                    DbPropertyValue As String, _
                    Optional DbPropertyType As Long = DB_TEXT, _
                    Optional DbFilename As String = "Current")
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim prop As Property

    If DbFilename = "Current" Then
        Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Else
        Set db = OpenDatabase(DbFilename)
    End If

    'add the property
    Set prop = db.CreateProperty(DbProperty, DbPropertyType, DbPropertyValue)
    db.Properties.Append prop

Exit_Handler:
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
      Case Else
        MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.description, vbCritical, _
            "Error encountered (#" & Err.Number & " - AddDbProperty[mod_Dev_Properties])"
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

' ---------------------------------
' FUNCTION:     RemoveDbProperty
' Description:  remove custom properties from a database applciation
' ---------------------------------
Public Function RemoveDbProperty(DbProperty As String, _
                    Optional DbFilename As String = "Current")
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim db As DAO.Database

    If DbFilename = "Current" Then
        Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Else
        Set db = OpenDatabase(DbFilename)
    End If

    'remove the property
    db.Properties.Delete DbProperty

Exit_Handler:
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
      Case Else
        MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.description, vbCritical, _
            "Error encountered (#" & Err.Number & " - RemoveDbProperty[mod_Dev_Properties])"
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

' ---------------------------------
' FUNCTION:     UpdateDbProperty
' Description:  add custom properties to a database application
' ---------------------------------
Public Function UpdateDbProperty(DbProperty As String, _
                    DbPropertyValue As String, _
                    Optional DbFilename As String = "Current")
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim db As DAO.Database

    If DbFilename = "Current" Then
        Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Else
        Set db = OpenDatabase(DbFilename)
    End If

    'add the property
    db.Properties(DbProperty) = DbPropertyValue

Exit_Handler:
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
      Case Else
        MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.description, vbCritical, _
            "Error encountered (#" & Err.Number & " - UpdateDbProperty[mod_Dev_Properties])"
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

Using the IDE immediate window properties can be added/updated/removed.

For example:

`?AddDbProperty("My Property Name","My Property value")`

Retrieving the property is readily done via vba

`CurrentDb.Properties("My Property Name")`

Thanks all for the also viable inputs!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to an external database in your VCS database.

How? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47099976/7296893).

Make sure your module and function names between the two databases don't conflict. Then you can just reference your const by using `MyModule.APP_TABLES_TO_BACKUP`, or if you have multiple projects with the same module and constant name, `MyProject.MyModule.APP_TABLES_TO_BACKUP`