# In Microsoft Access, what are the relationships between CodeData, CodeProject, and DAO..?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

What are the differences between the following sets of Microsoft Access VBA collections..? Some of them seem to point to the same data & child objects, but through different conduits. I'm thinking the DAO objects are DBMS-specific, but Access.⃰ Code.⃰  and Access.⃰ Project.⃰  are not, and get connected through Access. There is ADODB, which is another beast entirely. Also, it seems some of the collections may not exist if there no child objects of that type.

Given the mentions of SQL features, there seem to be three scenarios to be concerned with, but it's difficult to grasp:

1. A standalone ACCDB file.
2. A split database with two or more ACCDB
   files.
3. An Access frontend to an SQL server.

Object set #1:

1. Access.CodeData.AllTables
2. Access.CodeData.AllQueries
3. Access.CodeData.AllFunctions
4. Access.CodeData.AllDatabaseDiagrams
5. Access.CodeData.AllStoredProcedures
6. Access.CodeData.AllViews
7. Access.CodeProject.AllForms
8. Access.CodeProject.AllMacros
9. Access.CodeProject.AllModules
10. Access.CodeProject.AllReports
11. And of course CodeData vs. CurrentData and CodeProject vs. CurrentProject.

Object set #2:

1. Access.Application.CodeData.*
2. Access.Application.CodeProject.*

Object set #3:

1. Access.Application.CurrentDb.QueryDefs (DAO.QueryDefs)
2. Access.Application.CurrentDb.Relations (DAO.Relations)
3. Access.Application.CurrentDb.TableDefs (DAO.TableDefs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you should already know (since I told you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47099976/7296893)), you can store code in external databases, and refer to that code from another database.

The code in this external database might rely on certain tables, queries and forms to be present. But since it's ran on another database, they might not be.

That's where `CodeDb`, `CodeProject` and `CodeData` come in. They're fully equivalent to the variants starting with `Current`, only refer to the database where the code is stored, instead of the database which is currently open.

Differences between `CurrentDb`, `CurrentProject` and `CurrentData` is really asking for differences between apples, pears and oranges. They're all objects, but fulfill different functions. As ThunderFrame noted, `CurrentDb` is mostly DAO, and `CurrentProject` contains some ADO functionality (mostly just the connection), but also functions to influence the VBA part of the database, the database path, and many other functions. And `CurrentData` is something else entirely.

Comment: Ahh-ha..!! That's what the various mentions of scenarios using the word "library" meant..! Also, I hadn't seen the CodeDB object yet. Thank you for pointing that one out. I see now the difference between the two groups of objects: the "Current" objects are the database the user is currently running, and is doing the calling to another ACCDB somewhere, which is where the "Code" objects come in. I assume this still works, even when there are multiple other attached library DBs..?

Comment: Also, my apologies for not following up with the other thread. Oddly, I was just thinking about it this morning. Somehow I overlooked how many replies it generated. I'll get back to it today if I can.

Comment: Yes, of course this works in a multi-user environment, and one database can reference multiple databases with each their own `CodeDb`

Comment: If I wanted to use the object model to access the properties of the reports or macros in an external ACCDB (library, tempfile, addin, etc), how do I do that..? The only way I can think of is to place a function in the code of the target db that acts like a property-get, and returns a reference to CodeProject, and thus the AllReports or AllMacros collections from that particular ACCDB. [banging my head on most of the day]

Comment: @spinjector If you don't maintain need a reference to the external file for anything else, I'd just dim a new `Access.Application`, open up the file in there, and then use that to get the information I need. That way you have access to the `Application.Reports` collection, and most of the useful information is in there (for my use cases at least). I don't really do macros so don't know about that.

Comment: Holy banana splits, Batman..! Well, it's been days, but I finally found the hierarchical path to the macros of any ACCDB open in the current project, and it's pretty deep, weird, and uses various collections, names, & aliases that I haven't seen or used before. The path is as follows: Access.Application.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).Containers("Scripts").Documents("AutoExec"). But that's as far as it goes; no indication yet if/how the contents are accessed if I wished to.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. You're taking the long way round there, you can get to the `Containers` collection by just using `CurrentDb.Containers`. From there it's about right. As said, I don't do macro's, but the furthest I got with them was exporting them to a text file, deleting them, modifying the text file and importing them back in.

Comment: Awesome, you're the first I've seen to say this in days of Googling on it. Might I ask you to share that code? I currently have a morbid fascination with this, lol. The only thing I use macros for is like a Windows Shortcut. I make extensive use of the Access Navpane in my dev databases, and I drop 'macro-shortcuts' into groups so I can easily launch a VBA function that's pertinent to the objects in that group; the only command in them is 'RunCode'.

Comment: Well, the real pointer is use the undocumented `SaveAsText` and `LoadFromText` functions. Example usage: `SaveAsText acMacro, "Macro1", CurrentProject.Path & "\Macro1.xml"` exports `Macro1` to `Macro1.xml` (note: overwrites silently). `LoadFromText` takes the same parameters in the same order. You can just programatically find and replace file locations, form names, etc.. It's readable text mixed with quoted broken XML (encoding UTF-16 LE), so xml parsing will fail. You might be able to append blocks created in one macro to another macro.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Some interesting bits there. I'll experiment with this when I get done experimenting with the thing I'm already experimenting with in my current project, =-D

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference is in the ***type*** of database you are working with. A standard **Microsoft Access database** (*.accdb) will primarily use the `CurrentDB`/`CodeDB` object to reference the database objects.

An **ADP Project**, on the other hand, is kind of a hybrid with some data on the SQL server (tables, queries, etc...) accessed through `CurrentData`/`CodeData` and other objects like forms and reports residing in the *.adp file and accessed through `CurrentProject`/`CodeProject`.

The difference between `CurrentDB` and `CodeDB` comes into play when you have multiple database files involved, such as other Access databases referenced as library databases. Those library databases might have functions to interact with the parent application, and others that reference the library.

Comment: What are the differences between the 'Code' and 'Current' objects that are rooted in the Access.⃰  object, and those rooted in the Access.Application.⃰  object..?

Comment: They are functionally referencing the same thing. `Access` is the parent library, and includes global constants and top level class objects. I believe the `Application` object may be the default object in the library, which is why you can reference members directly from within Access VBA. (`Debug.Print Version` is the same as `Debug.Print Access.Application.Version`)

Comment: And are Access.CurrentData.AllTables & Access.CurrentDb.TableDefs the same as well..?

Answer (score 2):

In Access, the `CodeDB` and `CurrentDb` functions return `DAO.Database` objects.

`CodeDb` is the database **or** add-in, within which the code is running (which might not be the same as the `CurrentDb`.

`CurrentDb` is the currently active database (**not** an add-in).

Access 2002/03 added `ADODB`, and so they added `CurrentProject` and `CodeProject` functions for returning the ADO equivalents of `CurrentDb` and `CodeDb`, but being ADO, they have very different methods and properties.