# Access, #Name error on report formula if there is *any* error on *any* module

Tags: ms-access, report

I tried this on Access 2016, but I'm pretty sure this has always been like that since the first versions.
Let's use a formula in a report field, in this case Mid("abc",2):

[image: Formula Mid]

When I show the report, the result is correct:

[image: Correct Result]

Now, if for any reason i've got a syntax error in a VBA Module (I cannot exclude that other categories of problems lead to the same result), not related with the function I've used in my formula, the formula goes into an error state, displaying "#Name?" error message.

[image: Error in module]

And this is the result:

[image: Report with error]

Well this is quite scary because it means that a report that is already validated and used can always show an error and omit information because an error is present in an non-related module.
Potentially ALL the report formula could get broken because a bug in a module; in complex reports with a lot of fields, this can go unnoticed till a customer realizes that instead of a crucial information "#Name?" is written.

I would like to prevent this scenario. Is it possible to raise an exception in the case of a broken formula, instead of just showing #Name?
Are there any other possibilities to achieve this level of reliability?

Comment: The obvious answer is to make sure that all of your code compiles with no syntactical errors!!

Comment: ^Yeah. Add that Compile button to the VBE toolbar. -- Is this really an issue with a production database? Customers should get a compiled .accde, which you can't successfully create if there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not, at least not really.

There is really only one way to avoid this: make sure your code compiles. If your code can't compile, then none of the functions can be trusted. Since VBA allows overriding functions, that's a good thing, since you might've declared a function named `Mid` somewhere in that section that doesn't compile and might expect the code to use that. Not compiling equals "not a clue what's going on, nothing can be trusted".

For simple projects, the fix is to mash that compile button (Debug -> Compile) after every single change and to never accept a failure to compile.

For more complex projects, you can organize code in different files and reference them (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47099976/7296893)), and if one file fails to compile, that'll only affect code that references anything from that file (make sure to rename the VB project of each file to avoid name conflicts). For some projects, it's sensible to use this to keep data, forms and reports, and modules all in separate files.